# how to return text from pop-up window to parent window which can be supported by chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

I am returning value selected by pop-up window to Parent window. Its working fine in IE but chrome does not support it, how can i solve browser compatible issue.

```
//Parent Window


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Open-Popup").live("click", function () {
        var s = window.showModalDialog('AddDependentConfiguration?QuestionID= @question.QuestionID&ProjectModuleID=@question.ProjectModule.ProjectModuleID', window);
        alert(s);
    });
</script>


//Pop-up window
<script type="text/javascript">
    var opener = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.name = "modal";
        //        alert(window.dialogArguments);
        // alert(window.opener);;
        if (window.dialogArguments) // Internet Explorer supports window.dialogArguments
        {
            opener = window.dialogArguments;
        }
        else // Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome and Opera supports window.opener
        {
            if (window.opener) {
                window.returnValue = 'sonam';
                window.close();
                return false;
                //opener = window.opener;

            }
        }
        $("#Pwindow").val(opener);
    });
    //        function showDiv(Grid) {
    //            document.getElementById("Grid").style.display = 'block';
    //        }
    debugger;
    $(".select").click(function () {
        //  alert(opener);
        var $td = $(this).closest('td');

        var $tr = $td.parent();

        var QText = $tr.children().eq(1).text();
        alert('Question text' + QText);
        var QID = $tr.children().eq(1).find("input[type=hidden]").val();
        alert('question id' + QID);

        opener.$("#DQID").val(QID);

        opener.$("#DQText").val(QText);      
        window.close();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Your local variable `opener` seems to be not the same as `window.opener`. You probably should call `window.opener.$("#DQID").val(QID);`.